# RIGHT JOIN NOT RETURING NULL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the `NULL` values using RIGHT join. For example.

-- T1 --

```
AppId   |  PhoneTypeID   | PhoneNumber
   10   |        1       | xxx-xxx-xxxx
   12   |        2       | xxx-xxx-xxxx
   13   |        3       | xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

-- T2 --

```
   Id  | Description
   1   | Home
   2   | Work
   3   | Mobile
```

I am using the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.PHONE_TYPE_ID = T2.Id AND T2.Id = 1
```

And expecting

-- T3 --

```
AppId  | PhoneTypeID  | PhoneNumber  | Id  | Description
   10  |       1      | xxx-xxx-xxxx | 1   | Home
   12  |    NULL      | NULL         | 1   | Home
   13  |    NULL      | NULL         | 1   | Home
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want values for Id and Description for AppId 12 & 13? That doesn't make sense to me as there is no relationship between PhoneTypeId 1 and AppIds 12 & 13.

Answer (score 0):

Try This to get the expected recordset:

```
SELECT T1.AppId AS APP_ID
     , CASE WHEN T1.PhoneTYpeID = 1 THEN T1.PhoneTYpeId ELSE NULL END AS Phone_Type_Id
     , CASE WHEN T1.PhoneTYpeID = 1 THEN T1.PhoneNumber ELSE NULL END AS Phone_No
     , (SELECT Id FROM T2 WHERE Id = 1) AS T2_ID
     , (SELECT Description FROM T2 WHERE Id = 1) AS T2_DESCR
FROM T1
```

I although I do not understand the purpose T3.Id and T3.Description? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't correspond to a **RIGHT JOIN**. You always return the *AppId* from *T1* but only some *PhoneNumber* from the same table, no **JOIN** is going to do that, you'll need a conditional (**CASE**).

This query, for example, will return exactly your expected result :

```
select T1.AppId,
       case when T1.PhoneTypeID = T2.Id then T1.PhoneTypeID else null end as PhoneTypeID,
       case when T1.PhoneTypeID = T2.Id then T1.PhoneNumber else null end as PhoneNumber,
       T2.Id,
       T2.Description
from T1
     inner join T2 on T2.ID = 1
```